# Is Shechem in the time of Avimelech (son of Gidon the Judge) made of Jewish people?

Tags: shoftim--book-of

Gidon married a Pilegesh (second wife) from Shechem. Was she Jewish? She bore him a son Avimelech. He convinced the people of Shechem to agree that he should become king. Were the people of Shechem Jewish in this story?

Comment: What makes you think she/they might not have been Jewish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would seem so. First of all, Yosam, in his speech to the people of Shechem, speaks of his father having "fought on your behalf... and saved you from Midian" ([9:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.9?lang=he)), which wouldn't really fit if they weren't Jewish (Gideon didn't fight on behalf of the Canaanites or whoever, after all). Also, when Gaal ben Eved shows up (9:26), [Rashi there](https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.9.26?lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=he) says that "he was from a different nation," implying that all the protagonists up to that point were from the same (Jewish) nation.